# How to show actual value and original option id in Select option UI kitten?

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-ui-kitten, react-native-ui-components

I am fetching data from API for the options to display in Select component of UI Kitten

data format is like this

```js
const data = [
    {
       "id": 1, 
       "name": "General",
    },
    {
       "id": 2, 
       "name": "Other Category",
    },
    {
       "id": 3, 
       "name": "Public transport",
    },
    {
       "id": 4, 
       "name": "Help Support",
    }
]
```

It is showing the data in the dropdown but after selecting it is showing `option1, option 2` etc
but I want to show original data and `onselect` I want to get the original id of selected option
because by default it is taking index which is starting from `0`

I have used

```
  const [selectedIndex, setSelectedIndex] = useState(new IndexPath(0));
```

and I'm displaying my data like this

```html
<Select
  selectedIndex={selectedIndex}
  status="basic"
  style={[STYLES.input]}
  value={selectedIndex}
  size="large"
  onSelect={(index) => handleFaqCategorySelection(index)}
>
  {data.map((item) => (
    <SelectItem title={item.name} index={item.id} />
  ))}
</Select>;
```

any idea how to do it ? I tried document by it is not clear how to work will dynamic data

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though it's nonsense to me, I see only one way to set selected option label by filtering options again and assigning it `value`. Until you find a better way you can try like below

```js
<Select
  selectedIndex={selectedIndex}
  status="basic"
  size="large"
  value={data[selectedIndex.row]?.name}
  onSelect={(index) => {
    setSelectedIndex(index);
  }}
>
  {data.map((item, i) => (
    <SelectItem title={item.name} />
  ))}
</Select>;
```

**Note:**  If you use `multiSelect={true}` then you have to provide `value={[]}` as an array with labels or list of elements to render.

Comment: hi @Ravikumar thanks for answer how do i will get the actual id of selected option because actual id will be different from index

Comment: Seems that's not possible as per their component definitions [SelectItemProps](https://github.com/akveo/react-native-ui-kitten/blob/849fb480ee4e215a6c99ced01c82658a25d24e0c/src/components/ui/select/selectItem.component.tsx#L47) and [SelectProps](https://github.com/akveo/react-native-ui-kitten/blob/849fb480ee4e215a6c99ced01c82658a25d24e0c/src/components/ui/select/select.component.tsx#L59). At this moment the only way is remembering/retaining the indexes based on the options rendered order then finding the corresponding items/ids when needed.